# Monodroid: SQLite table created should have more fields

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, mono, xamarin.android

First of all, excuse my english.

I am workink with monodroid on Visual Studio 2010. I'm creating some tables for SQLite and I have problems with a few of them. The problem is that this tables are created only with the primary key (ID) when it should have more fields.

I'm using the Krueger's SQLite class to manage the Data Layer.
Next line belongs to MyDataBase.cs, where I create the DataBase and call for create the tables.

```
CreateTable<MyTableClass>(); //This calls CreateTable on SQLite.cs
```

Below I show MyTableClass.cs

```
using MyApp.Core.DL.SQLite;

namespace MyApp.Core.BL
{
   public class MyTableClass : Contracts.BusinessEntityBase
   {
       public MyTableClass ()
       {
           Field1 = 0;
           Field2 = 0;
           Field3 = "";
       }

       public int Field1;
       public int Field2;
       public string Field3;
   }
}
```

This is the BusinessEntityBase.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using MyApp.Core.DL.SQLite; 

namespace MyApp.Core.BL.Contracts

{
   public abstract class BusinessEntityBase : IBusinessEntity
   {
       public BusinessEntityBase()
       {
       }

       [PrimaryKey]
       public int ID { get; set; }

   }
}
```

And the interface

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp.Core.BL.Contracts
{
    public interface IBusinessEntity
    {
        int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Rarely, the other tables include the fields and the code is similar to MyClass.cs, just change the fields. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem lies with the Field declarations. They should be Properties:

```
using MyApp.Core.DL.SQLite;

namespace MyApp.Core.BL
{
   public class MyTableClass : Contracts.BusinessEntityBase
   {
       public MyTableClass ()
       {
           Field1 = 0;
           Field2 = 0;
           Field3 = "";
       }

       public int Field1 { get; set; }
       public int Field2 { get; set; }
       public string Field3 { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: The ORM only generated fields in the db for properties